# Spring Batch Meta-Data Schema for Oracle

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-batch

Where can I found the sql to create in my database all the metadata sctructures needed by The Spring Batch framework.
The application don't have the permission on the database to outgenerate them.

As suggested in [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/schema-appendix.html#metaDataSchema) I've try to use the sql provided in the [`org.springframework.batch.core` repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-oracle.sql)
but it's seems to be uncomplete.
For example it misses the column `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION  .JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION VARCHAR(2500)`, which on the other hand it's present in [the documentation snippet](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/schema-appendix.html#metaDataBatchJobExecution)

I've understand that this structure comes with the newest vesion 4.1 but also the (migration script)[https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/migration/4.1/migration-oracle.sql] doesn't seem to be right since it supposed that the column it's already there:

```sql
ALTER TABLE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION MODIFY JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION VARCHAR2(2500 char);
```

Where can I found the complete oracle sql script that creates the structure needed by the framework version 4.3.6 ?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/4.3.x/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-oracle10g.sql you can see the BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION.JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION column.  So you can use /org/springframework/batch/core/schema-oracle10g.sql from the classpath since it is included in spring-batch-core-4.3.6.jar.

Comment: ok it was only a matter of pointing to the correct branch. Thanks